# Fitting a distribution with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization, parameters, distribution, curve-fitting

I have data on Italian city size from 2011 census and I would like to fit them with a Double Pareto LogNormal but I cannot. I tried defining a function handle that is the log likelihood of the distribution in this way

```
ln_lik_dpln=@(alpha,beta,mu,sigma)                                         ...
    - sum(log(alpha) + log(beta) - log(alpha+beta) +                       ...
    normpdf((pop2011-mu)/sigma) +                                          ...
    log(normpdf((alpha*sigma)-((pop2011-mu)/sigma))/normcdf((alpha*sigma)- ...
    ((pop2011-mu)/sigma)) +                                                ...
    normpdf((beta*sigma)-((pop2011-mu)/sigma))/normcdf((beta*sigma) -      ...
    ((pop2011-mu)/sigma))))
```

and then minimizing it with `fmincon` and `fminunc` but both do not recognize beta.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It's tough to help with the information you've provided. Please post more of your code so the small sample you've given can be considered in context. Please also include more information about what happens when you try to run the code. When all you say is "both do not recognize beta," it's hard to know what's really going on. Also, reformatting the sample of code you have provided so that it occupies more than one line (both here and in your own file) is a good idea as it will be much more readable, easier to debug, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your anonymous function so that its parameters are described by a single vector rather than multiple scalar arguments. E.g.,

```
ln_lik_dpln=@(x) ...
    - sum(log(x(1)) + log(x(2)) - log(x(1)+x(2)) + ...
    normpdf((pop2011-x(3))/x(4)) + ...
    log(normpdf((x(1)*x(4))-((pop2011-x(3))/x(4)))/normcdf((x(1)*x(4))- ...
    ((pop2011-x(3))/x(4))) + ...
    normpdf((x(2)*x(4))-((pop2011-x(3))/x(4)))/normcdf((x(2)*x(4)) ...
    ((pop2011-x(3))/x(4)))))​
```

Then you can pass this function handle to `fmincon` or `fminunc` for minimization from some initial vector of length 4.